# FieldHandler and @Cache causing errors after upgrade to hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to update from Wildfly 9 to 10, which also upgrades hibernate from 4.3 to 5.

My queries have been working for more than 1 year without issues, but some of them throw errors after the upgrade. I read the migration guide, but I didn't find what could have changed or even if it's a bug.

**1st issue**

The first issue is related to the usage of @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL) in one of my entities.

Using it I started to get errors like the one below:

```
[Server:server-one] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Short field br.uel.acad.database.cae.model.CalendarioEscolarPK.anoLetivo to br.uel.acad.database.cae.model.CalendarioEscolarPK
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
[Server:server-one]     at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
[Server:server-one]     ... 191 more
```

For some reason, it cannot set a field of my composite primary key. This is a simplified representation of my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CALENDARIO_ESCOLAR")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class CalendarioEscolar implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CalendarioEscolarPK id;
    //other fields, getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class CalendarioEscolarPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ANO_LETIVO")
    private Short anoLetivo;
    //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Search method:

```
public CalendarioEscolar buscarProximoEventoNaoIniciado(CalendarioEscolar.Evento evento) {
    List<CalendarioEscolar> eventos = em.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(CalendarioEscolar.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id.tipEvento", evento.getCodigo()))
            .add(Restrictions.gt("datInicio", new Date()))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("datInicio"))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("id.semestreLetivo"))
            .list();
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(eventos)) {
        return eventos.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I remove the @Cache annotation, it works again.

**2nd issue**

The 2nd issue is related to join fetch. This simple query works with Hibernate 4.3 and habilitacoesAluno property (oneToMany relationship) is correctly loaded:

```
public DadosAcademicos buscarParaPortalEstudante(Long numMatricula){
    return (DadosAcademicos) em.createQuery("select da from DadosAcademicos da join fetch  da.habilitacoesAluno ha where da.numMatricula = :numMatricula")
            .setParameter("numMatricula", numMatricula)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

Using hibernate 5 that property always returns null. I found out that if I remove the fieldHandler from one of the entity's fields, it works again.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DADOS_ACADEMICOS", schema = "CAE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class DadosAcademicos implements Serializable, FieldHandled {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dadosAcademicos", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<HabilitacaoAluno> habilitacoesAluno;
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NUM_MATRICULA", referencedColumnName = "NUM_MATRICULA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private DevedorBiblioteca devedorBiblioteca;
    private FieldHandler fieldHandler;
    public DevedorBiblioteca getDevedorBiblioteca() {
        if (fieldHandler != null) {
            return (DevedorBiblioteca) fieldHandler.readObject(this, "devedorBiblioteca", devedorBiblioteca);
        }
        return devedorBiblioteca;
    }

    public void setDevedorBiblioteca(DevedorBiblioteca devedorBiblioteca) {
        if (fieldHandler != null) {
            this.devedorBiblioteca = (DevedorBiblioteca) fieldHandler.writeObject(this, "devedorBiblioteca", this.devedorBiblioteca, devedorBiblioteca);
        }
        this.devedorBiblioteca = devedorBiblioteca;
    }
    @Override
    public void setFieldHandler(FieldHandler fh) {
        this.fieldHandler = fh;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldHandler getFieldHandler() {
        return fieldHandler;
    }
    //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

If I remove fieldHandler, it works again. I know hibernate 5 had some changes related to bytecode instrumentation, but I don't know what that could change.

Anyone have any idea why those issues happened?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a bug caused by reading from the Hibernate's second-level cache when a number of elements cached in the memory is over a value `maxElementsInMemory` and `overflowToDisk` is enabled. I had the same issue during the migration.

See a raised bug for more information https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11222